# change the button status on permission basis react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here I am displaying three buttons invoices ,recharges and payments .
by default 'invoice' button is selected active and rest two are disable  when i come to this page . But if I hide this 'invoices' button through permission it should automatic shift to  'recharge' tab and recharge should be active .
please suggest .

```
export default class Financial extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state ={
            activeTab: 'invoices'
        }
    }

  render(){
    const { activeTab } = this.state;
    const { customer,rechargeDeatails,navigation,permission } = this.props;
    console.log("permission-------",permission);
    return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            paddingLeft: 10,
            paddingRight: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
            flexDirection: 'column'
          }}
        >
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', padding: 10}}>
          {permission.invoiceTab &&
              <View style={{marginRight: 5}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({activeTab:'invoices'})}>
                    <Button small rounded disabled={activeTab!=='invoices'} style={{padding:2, height: 28}}>
                      <Text style={styles.btnLabel}> Invoices </Text>
                    </Button>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>}
              <View style={{marginRight: 5}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({activeTab:'recharges'})}>
                    <Button small rounded disabled={activeTab!=='recharges'} style={{padding:2, height: 28}}>
                      <Text style={styles.btnLabel}> Recharges </Text>
                    </Button>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={{marginRight: 5}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({activeTab:'payments'})}>
                    <Button small rounded disabled={activeTab!=='payments'} style={{padding:2, height: 28}}>
                      <Text style={styles.btnLabel}> Payments </Text>
                    </Button>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
             </View>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
            { activeTab=='recharges' && <Recharges customer={customer} rechargeDeatails={rechargeDeatails}/>}
            { activeTab=='invoices' && <Invoices navigation={navigation}/>}
            { activeTab=='payments' && <Payments/>}
          </View>
        </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are setting activeTab state based on props you can check that in constructor if you have `permission.invoiceTab` then set the activeTab to invoices else to `recharges`

like:

```
export default class Financial extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const { permission } = this.props
    let activeTab = 'invoices'
    if (permission.invoiceTab) {
      activeTab = 'invoices'
    } else if (permission.rechargeTab) {
      activeTab = 'recharges'
    } else {
      activeTab = 'payments'
    }
    this.state = {
      activeTab,
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { activeTab } = this.state;
    const { customer, rechargeDeatails, navigation, permission } = this.props;
    console.log("permission-------", permission);
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          paddingLeft: 10,
          paddingRight: 10,
          backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
          flexDirection: 'column'
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', padding: 10 }}>
          {permission.invoiceTab &&
            <View style={{ marginRight: 5 }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ activeTab: 'invoices' })}>
                <Button small rounded disabled={activeTab !== 'invoices'} style={{ padding: 2, height: 28 }}>
                  <Text style={styles.btnLabel}> Invoices </Text>
                </Button>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>}
          <View style={{ marginRight: 5 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ activeTab: 'recharges' })}>
              <Button small rounded disabled={activeTab !== 'recharges'} style={{ padding: 2, height: 28 }}>
                <Text style={styles.btnLabel}> Recharges </Text>
              </Button>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={{ marginRight: 5 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ activeTab: 'payments' })}>
              <Button small rounded disabled={activeTab !== 'payments'} style={{ padding: 2, height: 28 }}>
                <Text style={styles.btnLabel}> Payments </Text>
              </Button>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
          {activeTab == 'recharges' && <Recharges customer={customer} rechargeDeatails={rechargeDeatails} />}
          {activeTab == 'invoices' && <Invoices navigation={navigation} />}
          {activeTab == 'payments' && <Payments />}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but ,now I am giving only one permission to invoices and hiding but if i have to hide booth invoices and recharges then..getting confuse.. its small one but littile confusing

Comment: on what basis will you be hiding recharges ?, in constructor you can modify accordingly.

Comment: ok now forget about  permission by default active tab is invoice if its not present its should go to recharge

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: yes but one thing suppose i would have 5 tabs here and if i have to hide all this invoice and recharge and make active third one or 4th one ..permission would be 
permission.invoiceTab , permission.rechargeTab to hide first two

Comment: I have updated the constructor in answer as per your question, check if this helps

Comment: you are great ,let me check ,let me check it dynamically ,like for invoice permission is false its hide so its going on recharge .let me make permision true and see it is coming on invoice or not